# Best approach read file from FTP server

Tags: java, ftp, apache-poi

I want to read ms excel file from Ftp server(not in my network) using Apache POI API.

I have small concern with performance,read a file from FTP is better approach or first download on local system then perform reading operation.

please help me  to choose better approach to read file.

Thanks

Comment: Personally, I'd bring it to the local file system, unless you're willing to try something like [Apache VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/), but I think It would be easy and safer locally, IMHO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the first one is better. The latter needs 2 more io-op than the former, and io-op is time-consumed.